# How do I create a loop repeating the following but each time deducting 0.1 from a?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, mean-square-error

How do I create a loop repeating the following but each time deducting 0.1 more from *a=10*? It should repeat a 100 times and then stop.
Thanks!

```
for i in x:
    yt = (a - 0.1)* i
    MSE = np.square(np.subtract(y,yt)).mean()
```

Comment: What is the content of y and what do you expect the final output to be? Also, please indent your code correctly so we can clearly see what is inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a while loop instead, like the following:

```py
a = 10
while a > 0:
    yt = (a-0.1)
    MSE = np.square(np.subtract(y,yt)).mean()
    a -= 0.1
```

That way, if a == 0 the loop stops and yt won't become 0. If that is what you are asking for. Due to accurancy problems, often a repeated -0.1 will result in rounding errors and could create unwanted results. Thus I recommand using something like this:

```py
a = 100
while a > 0:
    yt = (a/10-0.1)
    MSE = np.square(np.subtract(y,yt)).mean()
    a -= 1
```

Alternatively after the newest comment: Using temporary values which get compared iteratively every loop index:

```py
import numpy as np
a = 10
y = 5.423           #example value
tmp_MSE = np.infty  #the first calculated MSE is always smaller then infty
tmp_a = a           #if no modified a results in a better MSE, a itself is closest 
for i in range(100):
    yt = a-0.1*(i+1)
    MSE = np.square(np.subtract(y,yt)).mean()
    if MSE < tmp_MSE: #new MSE comparison
        tmp_MSE = MSE #tmp files are updated
        tmp_a = yt

print("nearest value of a and MSE:",tmp_a,tmp_MSE)
```

Comment: Thank! What I am trying to do is find a value for "a" that gives the lowest possible MSE. I have to repeat the following procedure 100 times:
- decrease a by 0.1
- re-calculate y using the modified a
- re-calculate the MSE
- check if the new MSE is smaller than the previous one
- if it is smaller, keep the new values for the MSE and a, otherwise discard it
- print the final value for "a" and the corresponding MSE
I know I have to use a while loop and a for loop...probably one nested into the other, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: For me, it sounds like you could solve this recursive. But it seems you are a beginner? If it's not urgent I could give an example later.

Comment: Yes, I am a beginner. It's semi-urgent. I want to hand it in tomorrow. I will continue trying to figure it out and when your free you can give me you example. Thank you!

Comment: I edited my comment with a minimalistic, non-recursive approach.

Comment: Remember not to use == 0.0 as your stopping condition! 0.1 is not exactly representable in floating point, you know, thus 10.0 * 0.1 != 1.0!